# Como obtener Cantidad de Palabras antes y despues de encontrar palabras con REGEX

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Buen dia a todos.

Estoy intentando obtener el conjunto de "N" palabras cerca *"Antes y Despues"* a una coincidencia, esto en historiales de gran cantidad en texto plano.

detalles a tener en cuenta:  el texto esta normalizado no tiene acentos ni tildes y todo es en minisculas.

Estoy intentando Buscar la Palabra "**xantoma**" o "**xantomas**" y obtener 7 palabras antes y después de la coincidencia, parando en salto de linea.

luego de varios intentos esta es la Expresion Regular mas cercana, pero no entiendo como hacer para que sean 7 palabras separadas entre si por espacios o caracteres de puntuacion o numero ,etc

```
([ ,:[\w]*]*\bxantoma[s]?\b[ ,:[\w]*]*)
```

Ejemplo Texto:

> 5. gastritis cronica corporoantral, lesiones corporoantrales sugestivas de **xantomas**

> 24/10/2009 evda hernia hiatal. gc antro corporal, gastritis erosiva nodular fundica, **xantoma** gastrico.  bx fondo : gastrotos cronica no atrofica moderada sin actividada. h. pylori: x/xxx.

> 7. gastritis cronica corporoantral, lesiones corporoantrales sugestivas de **xantoma** hipotiroidismo primario

Espero Obtener:

> gastritis cronica corporoantral, lesiones corporoantrales sugestivas de **xantomas**

> gc antro corporal, gastritis erosiva nodular fundica, **xantoma** gastrico.  bx fondo : gastrotos cronica no atrofica

> gastritis cronica corporoantral, lesiones corporoantrales sugestivas de **xantoma** hipotiroidismo primario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás buscando una expresión regular similar a esta:

```
((?:[a-z]+[^a-z\n]+){0,7})xantomas?((?:[^a-z\n]+[a-z]+){0,7})
```

```
txt = "gastritis cronica corporoantral, lesiones corporoantrales sugestivas de xantoma hipotiroidismo primario"

x = re.findall("((?:[a-z]+[^a-z\n]+){0,7})xantomas?((?:[^a-z\n]+[a-z]+){0,7})", txt)

print(x)
```

- Es muy común en las expresiones regulares ver `a-z` en vez de
  `\w` porque la expresión `\w` incluye, además de letras,
  números y el guión bajo, lo cual no es apropiado para muchos casos.
- La expresión `{0,7}` hace que la expresión regular acepte lo que está a su izquierda repetido entre 0 y 7 veces (en este caso).

Comment: Funciona muy bien , podrias explicarnos como esta compuesta no logro comprender totalmente , te lo agradeceria